# angular data not loading on tab load time

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

In my angular app i am loading data from controller. And i am using different tabs where data is loading. But when i clicked on tab data not showing until i don't click on inspect element. here are my controller code

```
    appControllers.controller('GalleryAppController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.itemsgallery = [
        {
            "name":"Mountains",
            "groups":[
                "nature"
            ],
            "src":"demo/img/pictures/1.jpg",
            "date":"10 mins"
        },
        {
            "name":"Empire State Pigeon",
            "groups":[
                "people"
            ],
            "src":"demo/img/pictures/2.jpg",
            "date":"1 hour",
            "like": true
        },
        {
            "name":"Big Lake",
            "groups":[
                "nature"
            ],
            "src":"demo/img/pictures/3.jpg",
            "date":"2 mins",
            "like": true
        },
        {
            "name":"Forest",
            "groups":[
                "nature"
            ],
            "src":"demo/img/pictures/4.jpg",
            "date":"2 mins",
            "like": true
        },
        {
            "name":"Smile",
            "groups":[
                "people"
            ],
            "src":"demo/img/pictures/5.jpg",
            "date":"2 mins"
        },
        {
            "name":"Smile",
            "groups":[
                "people"
            ],
            "src":"demo/img/pictures/6.jpg",
            "date":"1 hour",
            "like": true
        },
        {
            "name":"Fog",
            "groups":[
                "nature"
            ],
            "src":"demo/img/pictures/8.jpg",
            "date":"2 mins",
            "like": true
        },
        {
            "name":"Beach",
            "groups":[
                "people"
            ],
            "src":"demo/img/pictures/9.jpg",
            "date":"2 mins"
        },
        {
            "name":"Pause",
            "groups":[
                "people"
            ],
            "src":"demo/img/pictures/10.jpg",
            "date":"3 hour",
            "like": true
        },
        {
            "name":"Space",
            "groups":[
                "space"
            ],
            "src":"demo/img/pictures/11.jpg",
            "date":"3 hour",
            "like": true
        },
        {
            "name":"Shuttle",
            "groups":[
                "space"
            ],
            "src":"demo/img/pictures/13.jpg",
            "date":"35 mins",
            "like": true
        },
        {
            "name":"Sky",
            "groups":[
                "space"
            ],
            "src":"demo/img/pictures/14.jpg",
            "date":"2 mins"
        }
    ];

    $scope.activeGroup = 'all';

    $scope.order = 'asc';

    $scope.$watch('activeGroup', function(newVal, oldVal){
        if (newVal == oldVal) return;
        $scope.$grid.shuffle( 'shuffle', newVal );
    });

    $scope.$watch('order', function(newVal, oldVal){
        if (newVal == oldVal) return;
        $scope.$grid.shuffle('sort', {
            reverse: newVal === 'desc',
            by: function($el) {
                return $el.data('title').toLowerCase();
            }
        });
    })
}]);
```

Any suggestion please.

Here it is my HTML block

```
<!--End Scan------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>

              <div ng-tab-body="animated bounceInLeft" class="tab-pane" data-ng-controller="GalleryAppController">
                <div class="filterheader">
                  <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <menu-directive>
                      <div id="dl-menu" class="dl-menuwrapper">
                        <button type='button' class='btn btn-default cbutton cbutton--effect-boris dl-trigger'><img src="img/Btncategoryfilter.svg" class="svg" width="26" height="26"></button>
                        <span class="btn btn-default" data-ng-class="{'active': activeGroup == 'all'}"
              data-ng-click="activeGroup = 'all'" style="display:none">All</span>
                        <ul class="dl-menu">
                         <li><a href="#">category1</a></span>
                            <ul class="dl-submenu">
                              <li> <a href="#">subcategory1.1</a>
                                <ul class="dl-submenu">
                                  <li><span class="btn btn-default" data-ng-class="{'active': activeGroup == 'people'}"
              data-ng-click="activeGroup = 'people'">subcategory1.1.1</span></</li>
                                  <li><span class="btn btn-default" data-ng-class="{'active': activeGroup == 'space'}"
              data-ng-click="activeGroup = 'space'">subcategory1.1.2</span></li>
                                  <li><span class="btn btn-default" data-ng-class="{'active': activeGroup == 'nature'}"
              data-ng-click="activeGroup = 'nature'">subcategory1.1.3</span></li>
                                </ul>
                              </li>
                              <li> <a href="#">subcategory1.2</a>
                                <ul class="dl-submenu">
                                  <li><span class="btn btn-default" data-ng-class="{'active': activeGroup == 'nature'}"
              data-ng-click="activeGroup = 'nature'">subcategory1.2.1</span></li>
                                  <li><span class="btn btn-default" data-ng-class="{'active': activeGroup == 'people'}"
              data-ng-click="activeGroup = 'people'">subcategory1.2.2</span></li>
                                  <li><span class="btn btn-default" data-ng-class="{'active': activeGroup == 'space'}"
              data-ng-click="activeGroup = 'space'">subcategory1.2.3</span></li>
                                </ul>
                              </li>
                              <li> <a href="#">subcategory1.3</a>
                                <ul class="dl-submenu">
                                  <li><span class="btn btn-default" data-ng-class="{'active': activeGroup == 'space'}"
              data-ng-click="activeGroup = 'space'">subcategory1.3.1</span></li>
                                  <li><span class="btn btn-default" data-ng-class="{'active': activeGroup == 'nature'}"
              data-ng-click="activeGroup = 'nature'">subcategory1.3.2</span></li>
                                  <li><span class="btn btn-default" data-ng-class="{'active': activeGroup == 'people'}"
              data-ng-click="activeGroup = 'people'">subcategory1.3.3</span></li>
                                </ul>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                          <li> <a href="#">category2</a>
                            <ul class="dl-submenu">
                              <li> <a href="#">subcategory2.1</a>
                                <ul class="dl-submenu">
                                  <li><a href="#">subcategory2.1.1</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">subcategory2.1.2</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">subcategory2.1.3</a></li>
                                </ul>
                              </li>
                              <li> <a href="#">subcategory2.2</a>
                                <ul class="dl-submenu">
                                  <li><a href="#">subcategory2.2.1</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">subcategory2.2.2</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">subcategory2.2.3</a></li>
                                </ul>
                              </li>
                              <li> <a href="#">subcategory2.3</a>
                                <ul class="dl-submenu">
                                  <li><a href="#">subcategory2.3.1</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">subcategory2.3.2</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">subcategory2.3.3</a></li>
                                </ul>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                    </menu-directive>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <menu-directive>
                      <div id="dl-menu" class="dl-menuwrapper">
                        <button type='button' class='btn btn-default cbutton cbutton--effect-boris dl-trigger'><img src="img/Btnsort.svg" class="svg" width="26" height="26"></button>
                        <ul class="dl-menu">
                          <li> <span class="btn btn-default" data-ng-class="{'active': order == 'asc'}"
                      data-ng-click="order = 'asc'">Filter1</span> </li>
                          <li> <span class="btn btn-default"  data-ng-class="{'active': order == 'desc'}"
                      data-ng-click="order = 'desc'">Filter2</span> </li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                    </menu-directive>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
              <!--grid-->
              <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div class="row gallery" data-ui-jq="magnificPopup"
         data-sn-gallery data-options="{ itemSelector: '.gallery-item'}"
         data-ui-options="{ delegate: '.thumbnail > a',  type: 'image', gallery: { enabled: true  } }">
        <div data-ng-repeat="itemgallery in itemsgallery"
             class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 gallery-item" data-groups='{{itemgallery.groups}}' data-title="{{itemgallery.name}}">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <a href="{{itemgallery.src}}"><img data-ng-src="{{itemgallery.src}}" alt="..."></a>
                <div class="caption">
                    <h5 class="mt-0 mb-xs">{{itemgallery.name}}</h5>
                    <ul class="post-links">
                        <li><a href="#">{{itemgallery.date}}</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="text-danger"><i class="fa {{itemgallery.like ? 'fa-heart' : 'fa-heart-o'}}"></i> Like</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Details</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 js-shuffle-sizer"></div>
    </div>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
              </div>
              <!--End grid-->

              </div>

              <!--End browse------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>

              <div ng-tab-body="animated bounceInLeft" class="tab-pane">
                <div class="filterheader">
                  <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <menu-directive>
                      <div id="dl-menu" class="dl-menuwrapper">
                        <button type='button' class='btn btn-default cbutton cbutton--effect-boris dl-trigger'><img src="img/Btncategoryfilter.svg" class="svg" width="26" height="26"></button>
                        <ul class="dl-menu">
                          <li> <a href="#">category1</a>
                            <ul class="dl-submenu">
                              <li> <a href="#">subcategory1.1</a>
                                <ul class="dl-submenu">
                                  <li><a href="#">subcategory1.1.1</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">subcategory1.1.2</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">subcategory1.1.3</a></li>
                                </ul>
                              </li>
                              <li> <a href="#">subcategory1.2</a>
                                <ul class="dl-submenu">
                                  <li><a href="#">subcategory1.2.1</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">subcategory1.2.2</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">subcategory1.2.3</a></li>
                                </ul>
                              </li>
                              <li> <a href="#">subcategory1.3</a>
                                <ul class="dl-submenu">
                                  <li><a href="#">subcategory1.3.1</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">subcategory1.3.2</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">subcategory1.3.3</a></li>
                                </ul>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                          <li> <a href="#">category2</a>
                            <ul class="dl-submenu">
                              <li> <a href="#">subcategory2.1</a>
                                <ul class="dl-submenu">
                                  <li><a href="#">subcategory2.1.1</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">subcategory2.1.2</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">subcategory2.1.3</a></li>
                                </ul>
                              </li>
                              <li> <a href="#">subcategory2.2</a>
                                <ul class="dl-submenu">
                                  <li><a href="#">subcategory2.2.1</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">subcategory2.2.2</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">subcategory2.2.3</a></li>
                                </ul>
                              </li>
                              <li> <a href="#">subcategory2.3</a>
                                <ul class="dl-submenu">
                                  <li><a href="#">subcategory2.3.1</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">subcategory2.3.2</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">subcategory2.3.3</a></li>
                                </ul>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                    </menu-directive>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <menu-directive>
                      <div id="dl-menu" class="dl-menuwrapper">
                        <button type='button' class='btn btn-default cbutton cbutton--effect-boris dl-trigger'><img src="img/Btnsort.svg" class="svg" width="26" height="26"></button>
                        <ul class="dl-menu">
                          <li> <a href="#">Filter1</a> </li>
                          <li> <a href="#">Filter2</a> </li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                    </menu-directive>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
                search </div>


                 <!--End search------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
```

Comment: can you provide the code for  your view and the logic how the json is updated

Comment: please look at my edit question i have put html code there.

Answer (score 0):

put ng-controller="GalleryAppController" in your tab and check

Comment: please look at my edit question i have put html code there.

Comment: Ok. which tab creating an issue ..?

Comment: All tabs. i am showing all images on 1st time load. but they are not loading. here is url 
http://1stfold.com/taskbox/dev/POS/angular/#/app/scan/
You can see it by clicking 2nd green button on top.

Comment: Console showing an error ReferenceError: Ps is not defined, pls check in ur js files and test it again

Comment: But here on my end console is not showing any error. everything working fine just loading issue.

Comment: i have tried it but its will make issue on filter time.

Comment: Most likely, Issue is with the position. when it loads position is relative but when u click smwhr it changes to absolute and display all images